# css icon trick weird behavior on webkit based browsers

Tags: html, css, webkit, background-image

My issue is best explained with html code:

```
<html><body>
noicon <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="padding-left:20px; background: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-adobe.png) no-repeat center left;"></a>
<br />
icon  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="padding-left:20px; background:     url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-adobe.png) no-repeat center left;"></a>
</body></html>
```

this is a common trick to add icons via css. However, icons do not show in webkit based browsers on mac os x (chrome 9 and safari 5) when there is only one preceding space. Does anyone know how to make an link background image appear without two spaces (???) in front of the `<a>` ?

Comment: Have you tried using `display: inline-block` on the `a` element?

Answer (score 1):

put a zero-width space inside the link..

`&#8203;`

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="padding-left:20px; background: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-adobe.png) no-repeat center left;">&#8203</a>
```

Comment: Right, this is another workaround, but is this a known documented behavior? Why is this happening in webkit browsers and not other browsers?